# Как добавить gsap в gulp?

Tags: gulp, gulp-sass, gsap

Подскажите как правильно добавить gsap и именно scrolltrigger в gulp?
Вот моя сборка

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();
const watch = require('gulp-watch');
const concatCss = require('gulp-concat-css');
const sass = require('gulp-sass')(require('sass'));
const autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');
const sourcemap = require('gulp-sourcemaps')
const pug = require('gulp-pug')
const del = require('del')

gulp.task('pug', (callback) => {
return gulp.src('./src/pug/pages/**/*.pug')
    .pipe(pug({
        pretty: true
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/'))
    .pipe(browserSync.stream())
callback()
})

gulp.task('scss', (callback) => {
return gulp.src('./src/scss/style.scss')
    .pipe(sourcemap.init())
    .pipe(sass())
    .pipe(autoprefixer({
        overrideBrowserslist: ['last 4 versions']
    }))
    .pipe(sourcemap.write())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/css/'))
    .pipe(browserSync.stream())
callback()
});

gulp.task('cleanbuild', () => {
return del('./build')
})

gulp.task('copyimg', (callback) => {
return gulp.src('./src/img/**/*.*')
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/img/'))
callback()
})

gulp.task('copyjs', (callback) => {
return gulp.src('./src/js/**/*.*')
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/js/'))
callback()
})
gulp.task('copyfonts', (callback) => {
return gulp.src('./src/fonts/**/*.*')
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/fonts/'))
callback()
})

gulp.task('watch', () => {
watch(['./build/js/**/*.*', './build/img/**/*.*'], gulp.parallel(browserSync.reload))
watch(['./src/scss/**/*.scss'], gulp.parallel('scss'))
watch(['./src/pug/**/*.pug'], gulp.parallel('pug'))
watch(['./src/img/**/*.*'], gulp.parallel('copyimg'))
watch(['./src/js/**/*.*'], gulp.parallel('copyjs'))
});


gulp.task('server', () => {
browserSync.init({
    server: {
        baseDir: "./build/"
    }
});
});

gulp.task('default',
gulp.series(
    gulp.parallel('cleanbuild'),
    gulp.parallel('scss', 'pug', 'copyimg', 
 'copyjs','copyfonts'),
    gulp.parallel('server', 'watch')
)
);
```

Я скачал gsap.
Но в файле main.js при импорте

```
import {gsap} from "gsap"
import {ScrollTrigger} from "gsap/ScrollTrigger.min.js"
```

Я получаю такую ошибку
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как правильно импортировать файлы, чтобы можно было бы работать с библиотекой?

Comment: на официальном сайте [gsap](https://greensock.com/docs/v3/Installation) есть документация как работать через npm, вы почему все модули импортируете по одному а в ScrollTrigger решили еще написать min.js

Comment: а какой gulp модуль вы используете чтоб import работал?